# Rotate Marker with Google Maps API

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I am looking to have markers on the map with a handle that will allow the user to rotate the marker. Then I would like to get the compass heading that the marker is facing. Is this possible with the Google Maps API? Are there any good examples?

Comment: I don't this is in Google Maps API I'm afraid. You would have to write that functionality yourself... Unless someone already did.

Comment: [Streetview with pegman and arrow showing facing direction](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/streetview-simple)

Answer (score 1):

The solution I came up with is to send pre-rotated image to the marker object but instead of physical url a base64 encoded string of the rotated image.
so you rotate the image in a hidden `div` probably outside the map you base64 encode it and then you update the marker with

```
marker.setIcon({url:(The base64 string here of the image),origin: new google.maps.Point(0,0),anchor: new google.maps.Point(0,0)});
```